# How to change IIS SSL port for existing website

Tags: iis

I have an IIS website that is published with VS 2019. The site is HTTPS only with a self-signed SSL certificate. The current configuration is using port 443 and works fine.

Problem is that this is a staging website for Development purposes and is restricted by IP address in AWS inbound rules. The Live (public) site is on the same IP address and so I have no way to allow everyone to access the Live site but restrict access by IP to the DEV site.

Rather than adding an additional IP address with a monthly charge, the client would rather just change the port number on the Development site so that we have granularity in firewall rules.

I'm not able to get the website to come up in a browser after changing the bound port number:

Added AWS firewall rule to allow my IP address access to 0.0.0.0/0, port 8080.
Edited IIS Website binding and changed port 443 to 8080.
Restart website

Now when I browse to https://dev.myexample.com:8080 I get a browser message stating:

```
This site can’t be reached dev.myexample.com took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Am I missing a needed step? Do I need to republish the site with VS? Or create a new SSL certificate?

Also, rather than 8080, what port number is usually used for an alternate SSL port number?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue. Check your Windows firewall as well as your AWS security groups. I tend to use 4443 as an alternative TLS port - but you can use any port you like.

Comment: You can use SNI to host both `https://dev.myexample.com` and `https://prod.myexample.com` on the same IP address to avoid complicated setup, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

Comment: @LexLi I setup IP Address security for the two sites and added my configurations to Web.Config transforms. Works great!